# How do I connect to table that's not available through the Wordpress API?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, react-native

I have 3 specific variables inside a Wordpress MySql database. I added the Just Variables Wordpress Plug-in. It added its variables to the Options table in Wordpress.

From my research, the Options table isn't accessible via API.

I'm building a React Native app. In ComponentDidMount, I want to read those values from the db & show the results in the app. No writing necessary.

How do I connect to this database when the API doesn't provide access?

My goal is to have a set of 3 variables in the Wordpress Admin panel for a client that I can then access from the React Native app. The Just Variables plugin created a really clean way for my client to enter this data, but now I need access to it.

Thanks for any feedback & advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WordPress REST API which is now in the WP core. It allows you to [register a route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) and load whatever data you need on that route.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'so_41683154_endpoint' );

function so_41683154_endpoint(){
    register_rest_route( 'rr/v1', '/my-point/', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE, 
        'callback' => 'so_41683154_callback',
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return true;    
        }
    ) );
}

function so_41683154_callback(){
    $options = range(1, 5); # replace with actual options 

    return $options;
}
```

Your data will then be present on `http://your-site.com/wp-json/rr/v1/my-point/`

Answer (score 0):

I've found an Options API from Wordpress. I guess that is separate from the WP-API that I was originally researching. https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API